# How to calculate the number of consecutive days from Core Data data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have some payments(income and expense) which are added to `Core Data` and every day I calculate the total and also I show how many consecutive days the payments total was positive.

How I am doing right now is always get the total for previous day and increase a counter if its positive. This counter is saved using `UserDefaults`.

My issue is when lets say the app is deleted and reinstall, the counter is lost, so I am trying to find a way calculate it dynamically every time, but I don't think reading all payments for all days is a good idea in terms of memory.

Another solution is maybe save it using `Keychain` ?

Is there any other more elegant method? I don't really like the idea of saving this counter.

Comment: how reasonable a use-case is deleting and reinstalling the app?  Assuming you reset the counter if the balance goes negative, don't you just need to load the balance in reverse date order, and count until you go negative?  Should be pretty quick

Comment: @Russell: but don't I have to read all payments from Core Data to calculate this again ? Maybe I didn't understand what u ask

Comment: I guess it depends how many records you have - if manageable, then just read it all in.  If too large, read in batches of 50 days, or whatever?

Comment: I think is reasonable to read data in batches. Haven't thought about this. Please provide this as answer and I will gladly accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer

Assuming you reset the counter if the balance goes negative, you just need to load the balance in reverse date order, and count until you go negative?

Depending on how many records you have it may not be performant to read it all in one go. If that's the case read in batches of a manageable size (50 days, perhaps) and only get more data if you are still recording positive balances.

At some point, of course, you may just return "more than 100 days" as a valid response :-)